# SwifT: Generic function that gets generic protocol as parameter not working

Tags: swift, generics, constraints, protocols

Suppose I have this simple generic protocol

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype Element: CustomStringConvertible

    func echo(element: Element) -> Element
}
```

And this simple generic struct that implements it

```
struct FooStruct<Element: CustomStringConvertible>: FooProtocol {
    func echo(element: Element) -> Element {
        return element
    }
}
```

Lastly, I have the following function:

```
func callEcho<T: FooProtocol>(container: T) {
    container.echo(element: "some string")
}
```

This results in `error: cannot invoke 'echo' with an argument list of type '(element: String)'`

The solution is to change the function to

```
func callEcho<T: FooProtocol>(container: T) where T.Element == String {
    container.echo(element: "some string")
}
```

My question is: why is the `where T.Element == String` constraint necessary? The compiler knows that `T` is some entity that implements `FooProtocol`, and the protocol only demands that `Element` implements `CustomStringConvertible`, which my string literal does. So why does it not work without the constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say "the protocol only demands that Element implements CustomStringConvertible." The protocol demands that `echo` accept and return *its* Element, which may or may not be String. For example, I can implement this conforming type:

```
struct AnotherFoo: FooProtocol {
    func echo(element: Int) -> Int { fatalError() }
}
```

So what should happen if I then call:

```
callEcho(container: AnotherFoo())
```

This would try to pass a string literal to a function that requires an Int.

Answer (score 1):

`container` has type `T`, so that `container.echo(element:)` expects an argument of type `T.Element` – and that is not necessarily a string.

If the intention is to pass string literals to the method then `T.Element` must adopt  `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, not `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype Element: ExpressibleByStringLiteral

    func echo(element: Element) -> Element
}
```

Now this compiles:

```
func callEcho<T: FooProtocol>(container: T) {
    _ = container.echo(element: "some string")
}
```